# How do I set the width of a UISegmentControl in a UINavigationBar to maximum width dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

This is the code I am currently using. Unfortunately the UISegmentControl isn't max width for the bar. Is there a quick and easy way to make it the max width in code without needing an exact frame width to set it to?

```
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                                    target:self
                                                                                    action:@selector(addItem:)] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;


    UISegmentedControl *segBar = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil]] autorelease];
    [segBar setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    [segBar sizeToFit];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = segBar;
```

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

Here is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is slightly hackish and not knowing the entire behavior you're looking for (like what happens when it rotates?), I didn't immediately see a way to set the widths nicely. Try this out and/or alter it to fit your needs:

```
// this takes the width of the view, gets 80% of that width (to allow for space to the left of the nav button) and
// divides it by 3 for each individual segment
CGFloat approxWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * .80) / 3;
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setWidth:approxWidth forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setWidth:approxWidth forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setWidth:approxWidth forSegmentAtIndex:2];

// create the segmented control and set it as the title view
UISegmentedControl *segBar = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"First", @"Second", @"Third"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = segBar;
```

That produces the following result for iPhone and iPad:

[image]
[image]

EDIT: It's worth noting a few things as well, it doesn't look like your code is using ARC, which I would ***highly*** recommend, you were using setSegmentedControlStyle, which is deprecated in iOS7, and there's an easier/cleaner way to create an NSArray:

```
NSArray *array = @[object1, object2];

// the above is much cleaner than
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1, object2, nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for my needs. I am not using ARC because I am modifying someone else's old project. I'll be fixing that later.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UISegmentControl`'s API to set explicit width for each segment

```
func setWidth(_ width: CGFloat, forSegmentAtIndex segment: Int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would subclass UISegmentedControl if you haven't already and then override `sizeThatFits` like this:

```
override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: size.width, height: super.sizeThatFits(size).height)
}
```